# How to pass & (ampersand symbol) in ajax get or post method?

Tags: ajax, url, post, get, query-string

I have a text box to enter description 
If i submits that need to be send through ajax and store in db.

Problem:-

```
Example text in textbox:-    "Hi all & solve my problem"

in the next page i am getting till "Hi all" 

Remaining text is missing, If I pass through get or post method using ajax.
```

Give me the solution. How to get all the content I placed in text box along with "&"

Answer (score 5):

You need to urlencode string with [escape](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) or [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) functions.

Comment: if i use escape in the next page i am getting "Hi all [amp;_ solve my problem"   In This how to change "[amp;_" as "&"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have faced same type issue and find out solution that we need to pass data as a key value pair,

I had passed data in Ajax like:

data : email=" + email + "&name='" + name

But right way for passing data in Ajax is :

data: { 
     email : email,
     name : name
   }

Comment: This solution is great